# Search HTML source for string of 'cdn' after CURL request

Tags: php, curl, preg-match, preg-match-all, stripos

I want to try an establish if a website is using a CDN. It's a little wooly but I just want to check if the sourcecode contains 'cdn', based on that I can assume the site is using one. - Terrible I know. Unsure of any other menthod.

This is what I have

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$subject = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

//cdn check
if (preg_match("/(cdn)/", $subject)) {
    $cdn = true;
} else {
    $cdn = false;
}
```

It worked when checking a website containing this HTML:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

But failed when checking a website containing this HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cookieconsent2/3.0.3/cookieconsent.min.css" />
```

Dispite 'cdn' being in both.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It's because `curl_exec` returns `false` with the second website. Use `var_dump($subject);`

Comment: Hi, I have some error handling and it's not returning false. Im checking it for other stings which work.

Comment: Running the `preg_match()` with the second string hard-coded works correctly. So you're not getting HTML from your curl request, or perhaps this link text is generated dynamically after page load.

Comment: ah! The link text is being generated dynamically, that's why I can find it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second website was returning html, but the links were dynamically inserted after page load so were not being returned in the html via curl